# Best option for storing external database for iOS app

Tags: ios, cloudkit, data-storage

I am working on an app that will access an external database that needs to be able to load quickly. This is our own database, and the issue is where to store it for the fastest loading time. Currently, the database resides on a wpengine website, but it loads very slowly. One option is uploading a .plist file sporadically to the user's app when new data is available; it seems like that might not be very secure - although it would probably make accessing the data lightning fast. I was thinking that possibly CloudKit shared storage would be the best place to store the data if I wanted to keep it fast and also keep users from viewing it directly. I would appreciate any thoughts or suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried Realm? Have a look at https://realm.io/ They offer both local database and synced server solutions.

Comment: What would be the advantages of realm over CloudKit?

Comment: The biggest advantage is to leave the door open make your app cross-platform in the future. So you end up with a sort of CoreData on steroids. But that's just for phone's persistence. The Realm Mobile Platform allows you to have the same datastructure in your server and have them synchronized in real-time. It really is very impressive.

Comment: This isn't my main app database - I am successfully using core data with no desire to change at this point. This database is for non-user data, and can easily be moved in the future if need be. I just need it to be stored somewhere where it can be accessed very quickly, where traffic will not impact speed

Comment: In that case, CloudKit is a very good option. Here's a nice tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/134694/cloudkit-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: okay - I wasn't sure if CloudKit was meant more for shared user data or if storing our own data there would make sense. I guess the main concern then would just be how much it would cost if people accessed it over the free limit

Comment: It was designed for your intended use. Have a look at the scaling pricing although I believe the free coverage is generous and also grows with your userbase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, CloudKit will be OK for you. You can have a look at NSHipster's excellent summary [here](http://nshipster.com/cloudkit/).
You also have a link to a tutorial in the comments above. If you want to discuss it further, don't hesitate to contact me through chat.